# Enabling and disabling checkboxes with javascript

Tags: javascript, forms

I have been trying to figure out the solution to my problem for a few hours now. I'm still fairly new to Javascript, so please forgive me if I sound stupid. Sadly I don't know jQuery and I'm starting to think that it's inhibiting me to come up with a solution.

What I am trying to do is have a check box that enables disabled radio buttons. If that makes sense.

Example:

- Choice 1
- sub choice
- sub choice
- sub choice

**I would like to be able to click the first checkbox (Choice 1) to enable the sub choices. If it's not clicked, the sub choices should be disabled. :-)**

Here is what I've got so far:

```
<script>
function enableRadios(x) {
    var formElement = eval("checkbox" + x)
    if (formElement[0].disabled) {
        formElement[0].disabled = false
        formElement[1].disabled = false
    } else {
        formElement[0].disabled = true
        formElement[1].disabled = true
    }
 }</script>

<body><input type="checkbox" name="main" value="main" onClick="enableRadios(x)">
<input disabled type="radio" value="1" name="x">
<input disabled type="radio" value="2" name="x">
<input disabled type="radio" value="3" name="x">
<input disabled type="radio" value="4" name="x">
<input disabled type="radio" value="5" name="x">
<input disabled type="radio" value="6" name="x"></body>
```

I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Hi there, great question, Javascript is not my thing so all I can do is refer you to this similar question that maybe you could inherit into your work?  My assumption would be this part is wrong, but again I don't use javascript, "if (formElement[0].disabled) {
        formElement[0].disabled = false
        formElement[1].disabled = false
    } else {
        formElement[0].disabled = true
        formElement[1].disabled = true
    }" 
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5215048/javascript-checkbox-enable-disable

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass a string containing the radio name `'x'`, not pass a variable `x`:

```
<script>
function toggleRadios(name) {
    var elems = document.getElementsByName(name);
    for(i=0; i<elems.length; i++) {
        elems[i].disabled = !elems[i].disabled;
    }
}
</script>

<input type="checkbox" name="main" value="main" onclick="toggleRadios('x')">
<input disabled type="radio" value="1" name="x">
<input disabled type="radio" value="2" name="x">
<input disabled type="radio" value="3" name="x">
<input disabled type="radio" value="4" name="x">
<input disabled type="radio" value="5" name="x">
<input disabled type="radio" value="6" name="x">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/samliew/B6tF7/

Comment: +1: aint it better to pass `this.checked` as an argument in the `toggleRadios` function and enable or disable based on that value.